# JSON column query using laravel builder

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-8

I have a json column in mysql and i am trying query that column using laravel bulider. That column has an array of json object and i want query a Value attribute in that json object.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class SizeFilter
{
    public function filter(Builder $builder, $value): Builder{
    return $builder->whereJsonContains('sizes',[['Value' => $value]]);
}
```

and my json column structure is

```
 [{"SizeID":34,"Sku":null,"Value":"10","stock":2},{"SizeID":35,"Sku":null,"Value":"12","stock":0},{"SizeID":36,"Sku":null,"Value":"14","stock":0},{"SizeID":37,"Sku":null,"Value":"16","stock":0},{"SizeID":38,"Sku":null,"Value":"18","stock":0},{"SizeID":32,"Sku":null,"Value":"6","stock":0},{"SizeID":33,"Sku":null,"Value":"8","stock":1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `$value`? It must be a string. If it's an integer, the JSON search won't work.

I don't have Laravel, but I tested in the MySQL client:

```
mysql> set @j = '...'; -- your example JSON

mysql> select json_contains(@j, '{"Value":"10"}');
+-------------------------------------+
| json_contains(@j, '{"Value":"10"}') |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   1 |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select json_contains(@j, '{"Value":10}');
+-----------------------------------+
| json_contains(@j, '{"Value":10}') |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                 0 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

So make sure it's a string:

```
return $builder->whereJsonContains('sizes',[['Value' => (string) $value]]);
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. It worked! $value which I'm passing the filter function was an array and this is reason I was getting noting from that query